# Tensorboard shows single points for scalar values

Tags: tensorboard

I have a model in Keras where I use the Tensorboard callbacks. 
I have to run my model multiple times and each time it has to run for N epochs, so I have something like:

```
for iter in range(NUM_ITERATIONS):
    h = model.fit_generator(..., epochs = (iter + 1)*N, 
        initial_epoch = iter*N,
        callbacks = [tensorboard]
     )
```

Doing this, with N = 1, I obtain a result with NUM_ITERATIONS single points in the graph, one for each step. 
In the picture there is what I obtain.
[image: myresult]

How can I create a line with these points?

Comment: Is this a custom tensorboard callback? If so, can we see it? Why are you using this loop for running epochs, instead of running them all at once? It seems the issue is to do with how you name the runs. Each consecutive epoch must return the same name, and they will be joined automatically.

Comment: I solved it now, simply I had to put all the tensorboard files in a single folder. While I put them in different folders. Stupid question, sorry.